# How to set zoom on the basis of the road in Google maps API?

Tags: maps, zoom, google, traffic

I worked out a similarity Project a Google traffic, I would implement the same Google traffic visualization about the Data Traffic What a depending on the zoom level displays them or hides them.

For example, the first picture with a zoom

[image]

as second picture with higher zoom

[image]